# How to save a list in a xlsx file(excel) file line by line

Tags: python, excel, text

I am creating a  code that will extract all confirmed recovered and deaths in the whole world I want it to be saved in a xlsx file (Line By Line ) but all of the tutorial out there did not work.
this is the code that I use

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import COVID19Py
def confirmed_wrld():
    conf_list = covid19.getLocations(rank_by='confirmed')
    with open("confirmed.txt", 'w') as output:
        for row in conf_list:
            output.write(str(row) + '\n')
    messagebox.showinfo('Saved','The list is saved in confirmed.txt file in the same folder if you dont have confirmed.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action')

def recovered_wrld():
    recovered_lst = covid19.getLocations(rank_by='recovered')
    with open("recovered.txt", 'w') as output:
        for row in recovered_lst:
            output.write(str(row) + '\n')
    messagebox.showinfo('Saved',"The list is saved in recovered.txt file in the same folder if you dont have recovered.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action")

def deaths_wrld():
    dth_lst = covid19.getLocations(rank_by='deaths')
    messagebox.showinfo('Done', dth_lst)
    with open("deaths.txt", 'w') as output:
        for row in dth_lst:
            output.write(str(row) + '\n')
    messagebox.showinfo('Saved',"The list is saved in deaths.txt file in the same folder if you dont have deaths.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action")
covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19(data_source="csbs")
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("CoronaVirus Locator")
confirmed_BTN = Button(text="confirmed in the whole world", command = confirmed_wrld)
confirmed_BTN.pack()
recovered_BTN = Button(text="recovered in the whole world", command = recovered_wrld)
recovered_BTN.pack()
deaths_BTN = Button(text="deaths in the whole world", command = deaths_wrld)
deaths_BTN.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

as you can see I try to save it as a txt file it works but I want it to be in xlsx so other people can see it with ease.

Comment: Can you show what `dth_lst` looks like?

Comment: like the output? it is too long but I will try to paste it

Comment: here i paste it in paste bin so you can see the whole output https://pastebin.com/cAaBfnqP

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to flatten the dictionaries in `dht_lst` then you can use `pandas` library to save the `flattened` list as the excel file.

**Try this:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

def deaths_wrld():
    dth_lst = covid19.getLocations(rank_by='deaths')
    messagebox.showinfo('Done', dth_lst)

    flattened = pd.json_normalize(dht_lst)
    with ExcelWriter('excel_file.xlsx') as writer:
        pd.DataFrame(flattened).to_excel(writer, index=False)
        writer.save()

    messagebox.showinfo('Saved',"The list is saved in deaths.txt file in the same folder if you dont have deaths.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action")
```

You can install pandas library using `pip install pandas`, you might also need to install `pip install openpyxl` for excel support.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way I know is to convert the dict to dataframe and then save to excel file.

please install pandas by `pip install pandas`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import COVID19Py
import pandas as pd
def fight_corona(conf_list):
    d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(conf_list)
    d = pd.concat([d, d['coordinates'].apply(pd.Series),d['latest'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
    d.drop(columns= ['coordinates', 'latest'], inplace= True)
    return d
def confirmed_wrld():
    conf_list = covid19.getLocations(rank_by='confirmed')
    df = fight_corona(conf_list)
    df.to_excel('confirmed.xlsx')
    messagebox.showinfo('Saved','The list is saved in confirmed.txt file in the same folder if you dont have confirmed.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action')

def recovered_wrld():
    conf_list= covid19.getLocations(rank_by='recovered')
    df = fight_corona(conf_list)
    df.to_excel('recovered.xlsx')
    messagebox.showinfo('Saved',"The list is saved in recovered.txt file in the same folder if you dont have recovered.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action")

def deaths_wrld():
    conf_list= covid19.getLocations(rank_by='deaths')
    df = fight_corona(conf_list)
    df.to_excel('deaths.xlsx')
    messagebox.showinfo('Saved',"The list is saved in deaths.txt file in the same folder if you dont have deaths.txt file create one in the same directory and redo this action")
covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19(data_source="csbs")
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("CoronaVirus Locator")
confirmed_BTN = Button(text="confirmed in the whole world", command = confirmed_wrld)
confirmed_BTN.pack()
recovered_BTN = Button(text="recovered in the whole world", command = recovered_wrld)
recovered_BTN.pack()
deaths_BTN = Button(text="deaths in the whole world", command = deaths_wrld)
deaths_BTN.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I have tested this code on windows 10 and it works well.

Comment: Hello when I run the code I click the button for confirmed cases it create a xlsx file

Comment: only in for confirmed